# Deducting amounts after time has elapsed in PHP

Tags: php

I have a medication form where the user enters the name of their medication, the amount they collected from the pharmacy (for example, 24 tablets), the amount they must take at each dosage and the time interval between each dosage. I need the total amount of tablets (for example) to deduct after each dosage has been taken. I made out some code as a start but I'm not sure how to state “after the time has elapsed”:

```
//Deduct Medication Amount After Time

//Define Variables
$TimeHour = 3600;
$TimeDay = 86400;
$TimeWeek = 604800;

if ($MedEntriesTimeScale == "Hours")
{
$SecondsAmt = $MedEntriesTimeNumber * $TimeHour;
//When $SecondsAmt has elapsed
$AmountLeft = $MedEntriesPharmacyAmt - $MedEntriesAmountPerDosage;
}

if ($MedEntriesTimeScale == "Days")
{
$SecondsAmt = $MedEntriesTimeNumber * $TimeDay;
//When $SecondsAmt has elapsed
$AmountLeft = $MedEntriesPharmacyAmt - $MedEntriesAmountPerDosage;
}

if ($MedEntriesTimeScale == "Weeks")
{
$SecondsAmt = $MedEntriesTimeNumber * $TimeWeek;
//When $SecondsAmt has elapsed
$AmountLeft = $MedEntriesPharmacyAmt - $MedEntriesAmountPerDosage;
}
```

In accordance with my database;
`$MedEntriesTimeScale` - can either be Hours, Days or Weeks.
`$MedEntriesTimeNumber` - the amount of Hours, Days or Weeks.
`$MedEntriesPharmacyAmt` - the total amount originally collected from the pharmacy (e.g. 24 tablets)
`$MedEntriesAmountPerDosage` - the amount the user is supposed to take at each dosage (e.g 2 tablets)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the original pick-up date to use for calculating the elapsed time, here's one example (note: this could probably be written a lot simpler but I don't know what your goals are so I'm just leaving it the way you wrote it for now):

```
<?php
//Deduct Medication Amount After Time

//Define Variables
$TimeHour = 3600;
$TimeDay = 86400;
$TimeWeek = 604800;

// Example date
$date_picked_up = 'Feb 1, 2014 10:00am';
// Date converted into time
$time_picked_up = strtotime($date_picked_up);
// Time difference between now and time picked up
$elapsed = time() - $time_picked_up;


if ($MedEntriesTimeScale == "Hours")
{
$SecondsAmt = $MedEntriesTimeNumber * $TimeHour;
  //When $SecondsAmt has elapsed
  if ($elapsed >= $SecondsAmt) {
    $AmountLeft = $MedEntriesPharmacyAmt - $MedEntriesAmountPerDosage;
  }
}

if ($MedEntriesTimeScale == "Days")
{
$SecondsAmt = $MedEntriesTimeNumber * $TimeDay;
  //When $SecondsAmt has elapsed
  if ($elapsed >= $SecondsAmt) {
    $AmountLeft = $MedEntriesPharmacyAmt - $MedEntriesAmountPerDosage;
  }
}

if ($MedEntriesTimeScale == "Weeks")
{
$SecondsAmt = $MedEntriesTimeNumber * $TimeWeek;
  //When $SecondsAmt has elapsed
  if ($elapsed >= $SecondsAmt) {
    $AmountLeft = $MedEntriesPharmacyAmt - $MedEntriesAmountPerDosage;
  }
}
```